# What is the best way to convert a UI text to string in Unity (C#)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

i'm trying to make a code that changes the text of the UI by a string variable that's in another function but i get this

> error: Assets/Scripts/ChangeQuestion1.cs(15,26): error CS0029: Cannot
>   implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.UI.Text' to`string

What is the best way to convert a UI text to a string?
I'm sorry if this question sound noobish. 
Here's the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ChangeQuestion1 : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject databaseinterfaceinstance;

    public Text Question1;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        databaseinterfaceinstance = GameObject.FindWithTag("DatabaseInterface").GetComponent<GameObject>();
        Question1 = gameObject.GetComponent<Text>();
        Question1.text = Question1;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

UPDATE:

I already solved the problem, it was more complicated than that. The variable i was trying to print in canvas was from a script to connect with a database and i forgot to call some functions too.

Comment: `Question1.text = Question1;` doesn't make logical sense, you are trying to assign the `text` property of an object to be the object itself

Comment: `GetComponent<GameObject>()` makes no sense either ..

Comment: I updated the post, take a look

Comment: Try printing Question1. `Debug.Log(Question1Display.GetComponent<DatabaseInterface>().Question1); `. Does it print anything? Also, is `yourText` assigned properly?

Comment: I already solved the problem, it was more complicated than that. The variable i was trying to print in canvas was from a script to connect with a database and i forgot to call some functions too.

Comment: It took me days to figure this out xD  feels bad man :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Question1.text` is of type `string`, and you're trying to set its value to `Question1`, whose type is `UnityEngine.UI.Text`. You can only set its value to be a `string`, so it should be:

```
Question1.text = yourText;
```

or

```
Question1.text = "Your text goes here";
```

This is how it would look like in your code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ChangeQuestion1 : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject databaseinterfaceinstance;

    public Text Question1;
    public string yourText = "Your text goes here";
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        databaseinterfaceinstance = GameObject.FindWithTag("DatabaseInterface").GetComponent<GameObject>();
        Question1 = gameObject.GetComponent<Text>();
        Question1.text = yourText;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Comment: `GetComponent<GameObject>()` still makes no sense either

Comment: I'm trying to convert a ui text based on the value of a variable that is in another function. Sorry for not being verry clear.